# Gravar Retorno Json em arquivo txt c#

Tags: c#, json, desserialização

Estou tentando gravar um retorno de um JSON em um arquivo txt. Porém quando tento usar o `DeserializeObject` dá erro.

Tenho o Json abaixo (exemplo de 2 registros):

```
[
  {
    "TipoVeiculo": "Caminhão",
    "CodigoMarca": 501,
    "Marca": "AGRALE",
    "CodigoModelo": 34,
    "Modelo": "10000 / 10000 S  2p (diesel) (E5)",
    "Ano": 2012,
    "Combustivel": "Diesel",
    "Valor": 96041.00
  },
  {
    "TipoVeiculo": "Caminhão",
    "CodigoMarca": 501,
    "Marca": "AGRALE",
    "CodigoModelo": 34,
    "Modelo": "10000 / 10000 S  2p (diesel) (E5)",
    "Ano": 2013,
    "Combustivel": "Diesel",
    "Valor": 100932.00
  }
]
```

estou recuperando ele dessa forma:

```
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

e tento efetuar:

```
TabelaFipe deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TabelaFipe>(response.Content);
```

porém acontece o seguinte erro:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'TabelaFipe' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a
>   type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList)
>   like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
>   JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array.
>
> Path '', line 1, position 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se é uma lista de `TabelaFipe`, então você tem que usar uma enumeração, e não um objeto simples, na passagem do tipo:

```
var deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TabelaFipe>>(response.Content);
```

Ou então:

```
var deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<TabelaFipe>>(response.Content);
```